# Better Rails .erb code intelligence with Komodo Edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, editor, erb, komodo

Komodo Edit (6.1) is, for the most part, a treat to use for editing Ruby on Rails code.  However, it is lacking when it comes to .erb files.  There appears to be absolutely no code intelligence or completion for <% %> or <%= %>.  I know about the Ruby on Rails extension for Komodo, but unfortunately it is out of date.  Does anyone know of how I can make Komodo Edit a bit smarter when it comes to .erb files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Ruby code-completion in general is that currently Komodo doesn't
assign a type to block parameters.  So for example, if you type "for" after "<%"
you should see a list of terms that start with "for".  Suppose you select
"form_for", and end up typing

<% form_for(@item) do |f| %>

<%= f.[|]

where "[|]" marks the cursor location.

At this point Komodo (still) doesn't have a type for
variable f, so it doesn't offer any property or method
names after the "."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Do you know of an editor which supports block parameters?